# Generating the same "random numbers" with a seed in python on two different computers

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, random, one-time-password

I am trying to generate the same list of random sequences using the function "genKeys".
Using the same seed, I will get the same list, but only on my Laptop.

Running this code on my Raspberry Pi, I get a completely different list.

I guess the RNG is different.

Is there a way to "unify" the way numbers being generated or to implement an algorithm that will generate the same numbers?

```
def genKeys(number, seed, length):

    rng = random.Random(seed)
    seq = "abcdefghijklmopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 +-.,!%/?<>^_[]#$"
    key = open("key.txt", "w")

    for i in range(0, number):
        gen = ""
        n = 0

        while n < length:
            charGen = rng.choice(seq)
            gen += charGen
            n = n + 1

        key.write("%s\n" % (gen))

    key.close()
```

Background: These keys will be used as One-Time-Use keys to encrypt messages.

Comment: [os.urandom](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of generating encryption keys, Python's `random.Random` is not an appropriate choice; its underlying algorithm, Mersenne Twister, is not a cryptographic random generator.

Instead, there are so-called key derivation functions (KDFs, also called salted hashes) that take a seed as well as a salt to generate an encryption key. The salt is necessary in order to mitigate precomputation attacks. And if the seed is relatively easy to guess (e.g., the seed is a password), some KDFs deliberately take noticeable time and/or memory to compute, to mitigate dictionary attacks.

If your goal is to send messages securely between two computers (e.g., between a Raspberry Pi and a PC), it's hard to help you further since the right solution depends on your needs. For example, there are established protocols to set up a secure channel between two computers, including Transport Layer Security (TLS), J-PAKE, and others. One-time password algorithms include hash-based one-time passwords (HOTP), time-based one-time passwords (TOTP), and others. Security protocols in particular are far from trivial to implement, and are best accessed in Python via a dedicated Python package.

Comment: There is  [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom)

Comment: @kelalaka: I would have mentioned it (and other cryptographic RNGs), but in general, cryptographic RNGs (as opposed to key derivation functions) don't allow for random numbers that are reproducible between computers, as this question wants.  Instead, the numbers they generate are designed to be unpredictable to an outside observer.

Comment: Yes, the OP wants OTP. Maybe you should also mention that. Not practical, etc. In modern Cryptography, we use Hybrid Cryptosystem...