# Is there a way to generate Pseudo Random Numbers with a seed in TCL 8.5?

Tags: random, cryptography, tcl

I can make the rand() work but it only has the output from 0 to 1 and I can't use any seed value in that.

Trying to make a Pseudo-Random Number Generator in TCL and the use md5 hashing algo to make something like this, proc{secretseed length} that outputs a number of $length bytes.

Comment: `rand` is not appropriate for cryptography: the documentation says explicitly that it uses a "simple linear congruential generator that is _not cryptographically secure_".

Comment: Can you explain more why you need seeded random numbers, especially for cryptography?  Usually cryptographic random numbers are not seeded by the application.

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625642

Comment: tcllib has some packages dealing with random numbers, fwiw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can make the rand() work but it only has the output from 0 to 1 and
>   I can't use any seed value in that.

What about [`srand`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M33)?

Answer (score 2):

Tcl's `rand()` produces random numbers uniformly distributed over the interval *[0.0, 1.0)* (i.e., it's allowed to return 0.0 but not 1.0). It is *not* of cryptographic quality, nor really even suitable for use with monte carlo simulation (as no effort has been made to ensure that the underlying RNG produces a good spectral distribution). The seed for the RNG can be set with the special `srand()` function, e.g.,

```
expr { srand(123) }
```

To produce integers from a range, you need to rescale the numbers:

```
proc random {from to} {
    expr {$from + int(rand() * ($to - $from))}
}
```

To produce a random choice from a list, you do this:

```
proc pick {list} {
    lindex $list [expr {int(rand() * [llength $list])}]
}
```

Comment: If you need better random numbers, write your own code or use a library.