# Is there a way to use the secrets python module with a seed?

Tags: python, random

`Random.seed()` Is less secure than secrets, but I can't find any documentation on using a seed with secrets? or is random.seed just as fine?

Comment: If you're using secrets to generate a random number, you don't need seeds.  There is nothing you can give it that would make it more secure.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  The `secrets` documentation covers this.

Comment: *... or is random.seed just as fine...* Fine for what?

Comment: Can you explain more about your application and why you're asking this question?  Are you generating a salted hash with existing secrets (so that the seed serves as a salt)?  If so, there are key derivation functions that are designed for generating such a hash; by contrast cryptographic RNGs are poorly suited for this purpose since they're almost certain to produce different random numbers.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625642).

Comment: The question was useful to me, because I wasn't sure whether I could get deterministic output when testing output from secrets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't. [`secrets` uses `random`'s `SystemRandom` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/secrets.py), which [reads from the operating system's random device](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom), such as `/dev/urandom` on Linux. This OS randomness is based off hardware entropy, which is what gives it its security, and there is no way to seed it.

Comment: And there is no need for using Secrets with seed.

Comment: Actually there is, if your purpose is not security. A simulation for which random is not "random enough" might use 'secret' to do its work. We need it for the simulation to succeed  but we might also want consistency and therefore a seed. It might contradict each other but nonetheless the need is still there.

Comment: That is not a valid use. What you want is a different random number generator. [Read](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html).