# Seedable CSPRNG for python?

Tags: python, random

With the `random` module, you are able to seed it to get the same values every time.

```
import random

random.seed(1)
print(random.randint(1,100)) # outputs 18 every time

lst = [1,2,3]
random.shuffle(lst)
print(lst) # [2, 3, 1] every time
```

Is there a CSPRNG that can do this? For example, according to this question [How can I create a random number that is cryptographically secure in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936993/how-can-i-create-a-random-number-that-is-cryptographically-secure-in-python), `random.SystemRandom` is secure. But seeding it doesn't return the same thing.

```
from random import SystemRandom

s = SystemRandom()
s.seed(1)
print(s.randint(1,100)) # 81, 16, 100, 58

lst = [1,2,3]
s.shuffle(lst)
print(lst) # [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]
```

Does such a CSPRNG exist? or does this negate the security aspect?

Comment: If you are going to vote to close, could you at least explain why?

Comment: The current close vote (not mine) is for "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more:This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Why should it? I'm not looking for opinions, I'm looking for a CSPRNG that will return the same values when seeded, if such a thing exists.

Comment: Like I said, the vote isn't mine. I can't tell you why somebody else voted that way but if I had to guess, it would be because (idk, just a guess) they believe your post is "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more". Here's a meta post: [What exactly is a recommendation question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) you might find helpful.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59625642/generating-the-same-random-numbers-with-a-seed-in-python-on-two-different-comp/59633840#59633840

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `randomgen` package provides NumPy compatible CSPRNGs, e.g. [ChaCha](https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/bit_generators/chacha.html) which can be used as:

```
import numpy as np
from randomgen import ChaCha

rg = np.random.Generator(ChaCha(seed=1234, rounds=8))
rg.integers(1, 100)
```

Notes:

- I'm using a reduced round variant, 20 rounds is more normal but 8 seems to be enough for most purposes
- `randomgen` provides its own `Generator`, but it's [deprecated and moving into numpy](https://github.com/bashtage/randomgen/#warnings)

Comment: And the results are reproducible? and does is have a `shuffle` method like `random`?

Comment: @Haveaniceday yes and yes, e.g. see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html

Comment: Also, what is the `rounds` parameter for?

Comment: google is your friend!  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChaCha20